# Pass browserify a module, or get module path in node.js

Tags: node.js, browserify

I have two front-end application on Angular. And I made some common library for them. Before I used git submodules, but I want to move to npm. I rewritten that library as node package, and installing it with npm from github repo.

Then I want to pipe it through browserify and integrate with the rest of my Angular code. I am able to `require('MyUtils')`, but then I don't know how to get file of that module to pass to browserify. Is there some property like `__file__` in python? Or is browserify able to take module instead of filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your apps call `require('MyUtils')`, Browserify will automatically include the contents of the `MyUtils` package (and all of *its* dependencies) in the bundle it outputs.

Comment: The problem is, my other app is Angular app, and rewriting it all at once would be not very wise. And I could not do `require` in angular module. But I just got an idea inspired by yours. Create some file `browserify_incudes.js`, require there everything required, and bundle it. Thanks for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution to get filename of module, in case someone will look is to use the `require.resolve()` function. [Node documentation on modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)